# DateTime FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am trying this

```
var FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
```

and

```
var FromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I get this error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: Add you code. so can give you the solution.

Comment: You must add [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) in order to get the proper date in text.

Comment: What's your input?

Answer (score 0):

What is your TextBox1.Text value?
i guess you have wrong month and day value in TextBox1.Text

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("04/04/2016 08:30", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. **Pass proper date format. My textbox date is formatted same as dateformt written below**

```
Dim txtDateTime AS Datetime

DateTime.TryParseExact(TextBox1.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, txtDateTime)
```